# Python: access a parent attribute from the child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I have the following code that came up as a quiz question:

```
class Big_Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "dangerous"

class Cat(Big_Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = "quiet"

new_cat = Cat()
print(new_cat.x, new_cat.y)
```

Since the cat class is inheriting from the `BigCat` class, it should also have access to variable `x`. Then why is it throwing an error on the print screen line. How else can `new_cat` get access the variable `x` from parent?

Comment: You are not calling the init method of the superclass, so x is not assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After inheriting from the super class, you must call the parent's `__init__` (constructor). You can get a reference to the parent class by using [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Here is an example:

```
class Big_Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "dangerous"

class Cat(Big_Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = "quiet"

new_cat = Cat()
print(new_cat.x, new_cat.y)
```

**Output**:

```
dangerous quiet
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `super` to call parent class' `__init__`

```
In [1829]: class Big_Cat:
      ...:     def __init__(self):
      ...:         self.x = "dangerous"
      ...: 
      ...: class Cat(Big_Cat):
      ...:     def __init__(self):
      ...:         super(Cat, self).__init__()
      ...:         self.y = "quiet"
      ...: 
      ...: new_cat = Cat()

In [1830]: new_cat.x
Out[1830]: 'dangerous'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the constructor of the parent class inside the constructor of the child class in order for the child class to access the methods and attributes of the parent class. You can do so with the help of super() method.

```
class Big_Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "dangerous"

class Cat(Big_Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = "quiet"
        
new_cat = Cat()
print(new_cat.x, new_cat.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python there is a different approach than in true OOP languages as C++ or Java.

There is *no such thing* as declaring an attribute in a *direct way* in a class definition so that this attribute *will become automatically the instance's attribute:*

```
class A:
    an_attribute = 0
```

The `an_attribute` is an attribute of the *class* `A`, but **not** an attribute of *instances* of this class:

```
a = A()                     # an instance of the class A
print(a.an_attribute)       # 0 - so IS the an_attribute an instance's attribute?
```

It seems that `an_attribute` is the instance's attribute, but ...

```
A.an_attribute = 100        # changing the value of a CLASS attribute
print(a.an_attribute)       # 100; so it is NOT the independent OBJECT 's attribute
```

So how to create an object's attribute? Very easy:

```
a.an_attribute = 200        # creating an OBJECT's attribute

print(a.an_attribute)       # 200 — the OBJECT's attribute, independent of a CLASS' one
print(A.an_attribute)       # 100 — the CLASS attribute
```

From this moment the object `a` has its *own* attribute, different from the *class* attribute of the same name.

It means that different instances of the same class may have not only different *values* of the same attributes, but even *totally different attributes:*

```
b = A()
b.different_attribute = 500
```

Very weird situation:

- the object `a` has the attribute `an_attribute`, but the object `b` *of the same class* not,
- the object `b` has the attribute `different_attribute` , but the object `a` not.

Is there a way to prescribe / initialize instances' attributes in a class definition?

---

Luckily, there is a special method `__init__()`, which runs automatically when you create an instance of a class, and which automatically receives *just created object* as its first parameter (commonly named as `this`).

So you may assign to *just created object* an attribute by using this automatically filled parameter:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.an_attribute = 20
        self.different_attribute = 50
```

Now all new instances of the class `A` will have their own, *object's attributes* `an_attribute` and `different_attribute` (initialized with values `20` and `50`, respectively, which is not important here).

---

So, instance variables *are not automatically inherited by a subclass.* Other people already explained, how to go around it — not surprisingly in the `__init__()` method of a subclass with the help of the `super()` built-in function.

Comment: Outstanding explanation! Thanks bro

Comment: @Linh, you're welcome. If my answer was helpful for you, you may consider voting it up.